# Laravel chart not loading

Tags: laravel

i am creating a laravel project with chart. i went though the documentation but this is site when i did https://charts.erik.cat/. but i ran into the error with when i load the into the dashboard **Undefined variable $chart**

what i tried so far i attached below please check.please give me the solution for correct this

**SummaryChat.php**

```
   <?php

namespace App\Charts;

use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Chartjs\Chart;

class SummaryChart extends Chart
{
   
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

ChartController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Charts\SummaryChart;

class ChartController extends Controller
{
    public function chartLine()
    {

   
        $chart = new SummaryChart;
        $chart->labels(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])->load($api);
          
        return view('admin.dashboard', compact('chart'));
    }

}
```

**app.blade.php**
this page under the app.js i yield the chart js look like this.because i need to load js only one page which is dashboard only.

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

 @yield('js')
```

**Dashboard.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
        <div id="app" style="height: 400px;"> 
        {!! $chart->container() !!}
        </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

this under the @endsection i attached the js files based on the chat loading.

```
@endsection

@section('js')

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script>
            var app = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
            });
        </script>
        <script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.0.2/echarts-en.min.js charset=utf-8></script>
       

 @endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am understanding from your code, you are initializing
`new SampleChart`
But you have not imported it yet. Make sure you are importing that by

```
use App\Charts\SampleChart;
```

Here is the official link to the laravel chart that I have found:
https://charts.erik.cat/create_charts.html#initiate-a-chart?

And also in the JS section you can not use `$` sign in script. It is php variable sign which you are trying to use in the javascript.

Comment: i have update the code i have created the new Controller and tested please check same error displayed

Comment: try to ```@dd($chart)``` before return in the controller. Check if you are getting anything

Comment: nothing get it same error

Comment: can you check it via the any desk what is happing